# how to auto load modes in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am interested in auto loading models created by me at the run time. My models are located in application/models/. I am using zend framework 1.11.

Comment: runtime created models that are stored on the harddisk? I guess you want to autoload them at runtime, not create them (as when created at runtime they're already loaded)?

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed Zend Framework's "standard" setup, your models in `application/models/` should have class names such as `Application_Models_YourModel` with a file name of `YourModel.php` and the Zend Framework autoloader will automatically find your model in `application/models/YourModel.php` when you do a `$something = new Application_Models_YourModel()`